# python : refer to different pip directory

Tags: python, command-line, directory, pip

I have a user account (named tamtam) on a remote server, and therefore I do not have permissions to `/usr/bin/`.

**Current situation**

```
$which -a python3
/usr/bin/python3                    #no permission
$which -a pip
/usr/prakt/tamtam/.local/bin/pip   #have permission, "local pip"
/usr/bin/pip                       #no permission, "system pip"
```

Basically, I am able to install python packages to my local pip but not my system pip. But because my python3 interpreter is linked to the system pip, it can't access the python packages that I installed thru my local pip.

**What I would like**

I would like to install and run my own python packages. Can I link my system python3 to my local pip instead of the system pip?
If not, what are some workarounds? Thank you.

Comment: Try `export PATH=/usr/prakt/tamtam/.local/bin/:$PATH` before calling `python`. Basically, when you calling `python` in your terminal, the terminal first looks for `python` in the current directory, then it takes the PATH variable and looks for `python` in each directories, from left to right.

Comment: hi @user3063243, thanks for your response! My $PATH actually already includes that directory. And I don't have a local python, only a system python, so even though $PATH includes that /.local/ path, it still won't find another python, as indicated by `$which -a python`.

Answer (score 0):

This will force Python to run *that* `pip`:

`python -m /usr/prakt/tamtam/.local/bin/pip install <package>`

Then later (I recommend):

```
$ cd /usr/prakt/tamtam/.local/bin # first change the dir to where your pip is
$ python -m ./pip install virtualenv
$ cd /path/to/prj
$ virtualenv env
$ source env/bin/activate
(env) $ pip install <package>
(env) $ deactivate
```

Thus the `pip` you have access to will create ANOTHER `pip` that is isolated with an environment. You should have complete control over that `pip` and `python` from there on; more [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/).

Comment: Hi @pstatix, thanks for your response! I tried your first line, and got the following error: `$ python3 -m /usr/prakt/tamtam/.local/bin/pip install sympy
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding spec for '/usr/prakt/tamtam/.local/bin/pip' (ImportError: No module named '/usr/prakt/tamtam/')`

Comment: @tamtam See my updated post, I added the first line to the block.